# Asking for test: Calculator function javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, calculator

I have made a code that can run a calculation from text. When I tested it, I didn't find any bugs. You are sharper than me. Maybe you can discover some bugs in this code. When you know some improvements to this code. It would be nice when you let me know.

I also made a calculator with this code. Of course you can easily do it too. You can make a calculator that works with an input element and it can be runned using the `calculate` function.

```js
// JavaScript Document "/javascript/calculator.js"
// Defining variables
Math.a = Math.b = Math.c = Math.t = Math.x = Math.y = Math.z = 0;
// Defining root for radix sign
Math.radix = function (y,x) {
 if (typeof x === "number") {
  return Math.pow(x,1/y);
 }
 return Math.sqrt(y);
}
// Defining powers and roots
Math.sqr = function (number) {
 return Math.pow(number,2);
}
Math.cbr = function (number) {
 return Math.pow(number,3);
}
Math.cbrt = function (number) {
 return Math.pow(number,1/3);
}
// Defining angle functions
Math.cot = function (number) {
 return Math.tan(Math.asin(1) - number);
}
Math.acot = function (number) {
 return Math.asin(1) - Math.atan(number);
}
Math.deg2rad = function (number) {
 // It has to be Math.asin(1) because Math.PI returns one decimal too big
 return number * Math.asin(1) / 90;
}
Math.rad2deg = function (number) {
 return number * 90 / Math.asin(1);
}
Math.dsin = function (number) {
 return Math.sin(Math.deg2rad(number));
}
Math.dcos = function (number) {
 return Math.cos(Math.deg2rad(number));
}
Math.dtan = function (number) {
 return Math.tan(Math.deg2rad(number));
}
Math.dcot = function (number) {
 return Math.cot(Math.deg2rad(number));
}
Math.dasin = function (number) {
 return Math.rad2deg(Math.asin(number));
}
Math.dacos = function (number) {
 return Math.rad2deg(Math.acos(number));
}
Math.datan = function (number) {
 return Math.rad2deg(Math.atan(number));
}
Math.dacot = function (number) {
 return Math.rad2deg(Math.acot(number));
}
Math.grad2rad = function (number) {
 return number * Math.asin(1) / 100;
}
Math.rad2grad = function (number) {
 return number * 100 / Math.asin(1);
}
Math.gsin = function (number) {
 return Math.sin(Math.grad2rad(number));
}
Math.gcos = function (number) {
 return Math.cos(Math.grad2rad(number));
}
Math.gtan = function (number) {
 return Math.tan(Math.grad2rad(number));
}
Math.gcot = function (number) {
 return Math.cot(Math.grad2rad(number));
}
Math.gasin = function (number) {
 return Math.rad2grad(Math.asin(number));
}
Math.gacos = function (number) {
 return Math.rad2grad(Math.acos(number));
}
Math.gatan = function (number) {
 return Math.rad2grad(Math.atan(number));
}
Math.gacot = function (number) {
 return Math.rad2grad(Math.acot(number));
}
// Defining function to get the left parameter from an operator
function getLeftParam(text,cursorpos,pattern) {
 var leftText = text.slice(0,cursorpos);
 leftText = leftText.replace(/\s*$/,"");
 if (/[\d]$/.test(leftText)) {
  return String(leftText.match(pattern || /(?:\d*\.)?\d+(?:e[+-]\d+)?$/));
 }
 if (/[^\w$][abctxyz]$/.test(leftText)) {
  return String(leftText.match(/[abctxyz]$/));
 }
 leftText = leftText.split("").reverse().join("");
 if (!(/^\)/.test(leftText))) {
  return;
 }
 var cc = 1, cs = 1;
 while (cc > 0) {
  if (leftText.slice(cs).match(/\(|\)/) == "(") {
   cc--;
  } else if (leftText.slice(cs).match(/\(|\)/) == ")") {
   cc++;
  } else {
   return;
  }
  cs += leftText.slice(cs).search(/\(|\)/) + 1;
 }
 cs += leftText.slice(cs).match(/^(\s?[A-Za-z\d_$]*[A-Za-z_$])?/)[0].length;
 return String(text.slice(leftText.length - cs,cursorpos));
}
// Defining the same for right
function getRightParam(text,cursorpos,pattern) {
 var rightText = text.slice(cursorpos);
 rightText = rightText.replace(/^\s*/,"");
 if (/^-?\d+/.test(rightText)) {
  return String(rightText.match(pattern || /^[+-]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+(?:e[+-]\d+)?/));
 }
 if (/^[abctxyz][^\w$\(]/.test(rightText)) {
  return String(rightText.match(/^\w/));
 }
 if (!(/^(?:[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*\s?)?\(/.test(rightText))) {
  return;
 }
 var cc = 1, cs = rightText.search(/\(|\)/) + 1;
 while (cc > 0) {
  if (rightText.slice(cs).match(/\(|\)/) == ")") {
   cc--;
  } else if (rightText.slice(cs).match(/\(|\)/) == "(") {
   cc++;
  } else {
   return;
  }
  cs += rightText.slice(cs).search(/\(|\)/) + 1;
 }
 return String(text.slice(cursorpos,cursorpos + cs));
}
// Calculation function that can be runned by a script
function calculate(text, anglemode) {
 text = String(text);
 if (text == "") {
  return TypeError("Empty calculation");
 }
 text = text.replace(/\n/g," ");
 text = text.replace(/;/g,",");
 {
  // Checking every variable to make sure you can't run an illegal javascript function
  let vars = text.match(/[\w$]+/g);
  if (vars) {for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
   if (typeof Math[vars[i]] == "undefined" && isNaN(vars[i])) {
        return ReferenceError("Cannot read property \"" + vars[i] + "\" of \"Math\"");
   }
  }}
 }
 // Angle mode
 if (typeof anglemode == "number") {
  text = text.replace(/([^\w$]|^)(a?(?:cos|sin|tan|cot)(?:[^\w$]|$))/, "$1" + ["d","","g"][anglemode] + "$2");
 }
 // Adding absolute values
 while (typeof text == "string") {
  let cur = text.indexOf("|");
    // Loop untill there is no vertical bar (I couldn't use while (true) because my editor should think it is a mistake)
  if (cur === -1) {
   break;
  }
  if (typeof getRightParam(text,cur+1) == "string") {
   text = text.replace(/\|/,"abs(\n");
  } else if (typeof getLeftParam(text,cur) == "string") {
   text = text.replace(/\|/,"\n)");
  } else {
   return SyntaxError("Unexpected token |");
  }
 }
 // When a double vertical bar is detected, match it as an binary parameter
 text = text.replace(/\n\)abs\(\n/g,"|");
 text = text.replace(/\n/g,"");
 // Adding some parameters
 while (typeof text == "string") {
  let cur = text.indexOf("^");
  if (cur === -1) {
   break;
  }
  let number1 = getLeftParam(text,cur);
  let number2 = getRightParam(text,cur+1);
  if (typeof number1 != "string" || typeof number2 != "string") {
   return SyntaxError("Unexpected token ^");
  }
  text = text.slice(0,text.lastIndexOf(number1,cur)) + "pow(" + number1 + "," + number2 + ")" + text.slice(text.indexOf(number2,cur) + number2.length);
 }
 while (typeof text == "string") {
  let cur = text.indexOf("\u221a");
  if (cur === -1) {
   break;
  }
  let number = getRightParam(text,cur+1,/^[+-]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+(?:e[+-]\d+)?(?:&[+-]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+(?:e[+-]\d+)?)?/);
  if (typeof number != "string") {
   return SyntaxError("Unexpected token \u221a");
  }
  number = number.replace(/&/,",");
  let ilength = number.length;
  if (number[0] != "(") {
   number = "(" + number + ")";
  }
  text = text.slice(0,cur) + "radix" + number + text.slice(ilength + cur + 1);
 }
 // Running the code
 with (Math) {
  try {
   var output = Number(eval(text));
   if (isNaN(output) || typeof output != "number") {
    throw TypeError("The result of \"" + text + "\" is not a valid number");
   }
   if (Math.abs(output) === Infinity) {
    throw ReferenceError("The result of \"" + text + "\" is outside range");
   }
   return output;
  } catch (err) {
   return err;
  }
 }
}
// Run an example
console.log(calculate("c=\u221a(3^2+4^2)"))
```

Comment: Fixed bug at line 162: Angle mode don't match functions at the start of a text

Comment: Fixed bug at line 154: When there is not a variable nor number, the function will break itself instead of returning an error.

Comment: Please stop editing the code in your question, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4):

First off, my basic maths is a bit rusty, but is `radix` correct? Shouldn't `Math.pow(x,1/y)` be `Math.pow(y,1/x)`?

I'm not a big fan of "extending" the native `Math` object. The `Math` object isn't a regular JavaScript object so you shouldn't assume that all implementations will allow you to add new properties to it. It would be better to create your own object and copy the properties and methods needed over from `Math`.

The code in general leans a bit to the cryptic side. Especially the many regular expressions urgently need some comments and the code could be split up into functions with descriptive names.

The use of the `String` constructor seems unnecessary in most places and could be replaced with more readable alternatives.

Checking the return values from `getLeft/RightParam` with `typeof` seems overkill. I'd use a simple truthy check (`if (number) {`) instead.

The `getLeftParam` and `getRightParam` functions share a lot of similar code.

The repeated use of `while (typeof text == "string") {` looks strange to me, because in as far as I can see in all cases the condition never becomes `false`.

Error handling seems inconsistent. Sometimes errors are returned, sometimes thrown. And the choices of error objects (`ReferenceError`, `TypeError`, etc.) seem arbitrary.

And as a pure gut feeling I don't think the code supports arbitrary deep brackets.

Finally, while I do think this can be valid use of "evil" `eval`, you do put a lot of (necessary) work into validating and replacing in order to extend the syntax and use it safely. However I believe it wouldn't be much more work to instead write a full parser/interpreter that avoids using `eval`.

Comment: It has to return the error to allow giving the error at your own way.
For example: `alert(calculate("foo*a",1))` alerts _ReferenceError: Cannot read property "foo" of "Math"_

Comment: You should ask me why I used ```while (typeof text === "string")```. I think ```while (true)``` is also a strange looking code. So the question is: what is the alternate way.

Comment: `while (true)` is certainly better than using an irrelevant expression. I spent quite a while trying to figure out when the expression turns false. There are several ways to avoid `while (true)`, that easily can be googled.